# sshtunnel: I can access ssh gateway with CLI, DBeaver, or Paramiko, but not with sshtunnel

Tags: python, paramiko, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to access a PostgreSQL database through a ssh tunnel. Unfortunately I can't do it from a Python script using sshtunnel.

- From DBeaver, it works. Main server:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btDOb.png)
  and ssh config:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QRwg.png)
- From CLI, it works:

```
    ssh -p 1322 admin@xx.xxx.xxx.xx -L 6432:xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com:5432 -i /home/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.pem
```

- In a Python script, using paramiko, I can connect to the ssh gateway:

```
    import paramiko
    
    mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.pem')
    transport = paramiko.Transport(('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 1322))
    transport.connect(username='admin', pkey=mypkey)
    print('Connected!')
    transport.close()
```

- But when trying to access to the database with sshtunnel, it doesn't work... My Python script:

```
    import sshtunnel
    import paramiko
    mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/home/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.pem')

    server = sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
        ('xx.xxx.xxx.xx', 1322),
        ssh_username='admin',
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=('xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com', 6432),
        local_bind_address=('xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com', 5432),
        debug_level='TRACE',
    )
    server.start()
    server.stop()
```

I got the following error message:

```
2021-06-25 18:49:31,520| INF | MainThrea/1060@sshtunnel | 1 keys loaded from agent
2021-06-25 18:49:31,539| DEB | MainThrea/1310@sshtunnel | Private key file (/home/xxxxxxxx/.ssh/id_rsa, <class 'paramiko.rsakey.RSAKey'>) successfully loaded
2021-06-25 18:49:31,539| INF | MainThrea/1117@sshtunnel | 2 key(s) loaded
2021-06-25 18:49:31,539| INF | MainThrea/0981@sshtunnel | Connecting to gateway: xx.xxx.xxx.xx:1322 as user 'admin'
2021-06-25 18:49:31,539| DEB | MainThrea/0984@sshtunnel | Concurrent connections allowed: True
2021-06-25 18:49:31,539| DEB | MainThrea/1401@sshtunnel | Trying to log in with key: b'a5166fbdcdc61d04cd7xxxxxxxxxxxx'
2021-06-25 18:49:31,539| DEB | MainThrea/1185@sshtunnel | Connecting via proxy: 'xx.xxx.xxx.xx'
2021-06-25 18:49:46,579| ERR |  Thread-1/1819@transport | Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2211, in _check_banner
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |     buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 380, in readline
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |     buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 622, in _read_timeout
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |     raise socket.timeout()
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | socket.timeout
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | 
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | 
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2039, in run
2021-06-25 18:49:46,600| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |     self._check_banner()
2021-06-25 18:49:46,601| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2216, in _check_banner
2021-06-25 18:49:46,601| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport |     "Error reading SSH protocol banner" + str(e)
2021-06-25 18:49:46,601| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner
2021-06-25 18:49:46,601| ERR |  Thread-1/1817@transport | 
2021-06-25 18:49:46,601| ERR | MainThrea/1223@sshtunnel | Could not connect to gateway xx.xxx.xxx.xx:1322 : Error reading SSH protocol banner
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect_jarvis_db.py", line 41, in <module>
    server.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1332, in start
    reason='Could not establish session to SSH gateway')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1174, in _raise
    raise exception(reason)
sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway
```

I made many trials without success. Regarding the error message, I saw that "2 keys are loaded". I wonder if it could be the reason for this issue, but if yes I don't know how to just use the xxxx.pem key file...

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the solution: even if I specify the .pem key file, my private key file (in .ssh folder) was read (see line 2), that causes the issue. The solution is to add:

```
ssh_config_file=None
```

in the option when calling sshtunnel.

Comment: While I do not object that setting `ssh_config_file=None` might have helped you, I do not think that *"Error reading SSH protocol banner"* can be caused by a private key in your `.ssh` folder. Moreover any `IdentityFile` in `.ssh/config` is superseded by `ssh_pkey` argument that you set. Based on *"Connecting via proxy"*, the problem was more likely the `ProxyCommand` directive, which you can override using `ssh_proxy=None`.

Comment: You're right, thanks for your comment. From the message, the issue is probably more related to this proxy configuration, and not to the private key... Even if the ```ssh_config=None``` solves the issue, I have to look deeper in this proxy configuration...